# ethernet cable configuration with possibility to connect one computer at the end or at the middle of the cable

Tags: networking, configuration, ethernet, schema

I would like to know if this Ethernet configuration would work.

[ethernet configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBSW6.png)

Of course, only one device could be connected to either socket 1 or socket 2.

The cables between router and socket 1 is 10 meters long. Same length between socket 1 and socket 2.

Thank you

Comment: What's the purpose of this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In a house, I have a router on the first floor, and I want to be able to connect a maximum of device either on the second or third floor. I'd like to avoid switch as much as possible. So if this solution works, it's good because it will allow more flexibility. Just need to be careful not to connect more than one device on the line.

Comment: This is an ugly hack. Just buy a second-hand switch and be done with it. I bet you can find someone who will *give* you one if money is the problem here.

Comment: Or buy some power line networking adapters. Or buy a wireless access point.

Answer (score 2):

As you may have noticed through the years, the specifications of Ethernet cables have been improved to allow for faster and faster speeds without impacting the capability of reaching good distances (around 100 meters).  Lots of tiny details impact how the cable can provide such a good signal impermeability.

While nothing will stop you from trying what you want to do if you do it well, don't be surprised if it reduces the maximum achievable speeds or causes the connection to become unstable in certain unpredictable circumstances.

Note that the RJ45 wires are twisted pairs, unlike your schema which appears as a straight cable.

Also, I couldn't figure out **any** good reason for such an unusual connection.  There is **absolutely no benefit** for the trouble you'll go through just to make a bad connection in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a modern router, yes the straight connection would work.

Unless you need to make it like this, avoiding termination points and just simply running the wires would work better. But if the connections/sockets are done well, this should not have any significant performance and stability issues. You just need to remember not to put 2 computers there.

This is like a basic electrical outlet setup for LAN.